# Comodo wildcard ssl certificate and Haproxy

Tags: ssl, https, haproxy

I've purchased Comodo Wildard SSL certificate and trying to make it work with Haproxy

I've got those files from comodo:

```
Root CA Certificate - AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
Your COMODO SSL Wildcard Certificate - STAR_mydomain_com.crt
```

Haproxy seems need to have PEM certificate, I've found an article how to make PEM certificate - https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1081/0/creating-a-pem-file-for-ssl-certificate-installation

Doing that by running

```
cat STAR_mydomain_com.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt STAR_mydomain_com.crt > certificates.pem
```

or

```
cat STAR_mydomain_com.crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt STAR_mydomain_com.crt > certificates.pem
```

But when I try to use restult file with haproxy:

```
bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/certificates.pem
```

I see the error:

```
[ALERT] 073/104341 (13) : Proxy 'www-https': no SSL certificate specified for bind '0.0.0.0:443' at [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:37] (use 'crt').
[ALERT] 073/104341 (13) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
   ...fail!
```

It's working with self signed certificate but not with Comodo's one

I've tried to google situation but cannot find clearly what's wrong.

Can someone advise how can I make purchased certificate work with haproxy

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate `STAR_mydomain_com.csr` & `STAR_mydomain_com.key` to `STAR_mydomain_com.pem`, this is how HAproxy understands certificate.
Add below backend to `haproxy.cfg`
`frontend https-port443
    bind *:443 ssl crt /path/to/STAR_mydomain_com.pem
    mode   http`

Concatenate the following into a single PEM file ordered by:

1. Private Key
2. Your domain's cert
3. Intermediate certs
4. Root cert

Comment: `crt` not `csr`